# C# app with Data.odbc doesnt work on different machine..what to include?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, publishing

I have an app with the use of namespace data.odbc in order to work with MySQL. I have tried it on different PC, the app works but when the odbc object should work, it does nothing. I suppose something is missing - I  thought its automatically included.
I have looked into app files - all are included. I have tried Add reference but there is no system.data.odbc :(
EDIT: In the code I am not using any references to stuff like MySQL Connector and it works on my machine.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe install the connector on the PC

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/)

EDIT:
'Does nothing' as in no results? No error what so ever?
Install MySQL drivers on target machine [LINK](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial139_Connecting-to-MySQL-with-Csharp-and-ODBC.html)

Comment: I thought with the OdBc I wont need anything like that. It is possible to include the files with the app?